# How do I select ONLY an inner div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a function run only when the outer div is clicked. When I click the inner div, nothing should happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/hg277/

html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.inner {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('div').on('click',function(e){

  if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('inner')){
      // don't do anything
      console.log("don't run");
  }

  if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('outer')){
      // do something
      console.log("run");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

(1) Attach click handlers to both outer and inner, and have the inner click handler call `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
    // Code here is executed when outer is clicked, but not inner.
}).find('.inner').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kWMD/2/)

(2) Attach a click handler to just outer, but have it check if the click propagated up from inner (or a descendant of inner):

```
$('.outer').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.inner')
            && $(event.target).parentsUntil(this, '.inner').length == 0) {
        // Code here is executed when outer is clicked, but not inner.
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sMP5P/3/)

Note: Both of the above methods handle the cases where the user clicks on a descendant of the inner div or a descendant of the outer div.

Comment: My solution solved the particular case I was dealing with, but this answer seems more thorough so I'm marking it as the best.

Answer (score 0):

I needed .stopPropagation();

so it ended up looking like this:

```
$('div').on('click',function(e){

  e.stopPropagation();

  if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('inner')){
      // don't do anything
      console.log("don't run");
  }

  if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('outer')){
      // do something
      console.log("run");
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not handle the case where the inner div has an element inside it, and the user clicks on that nested element. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAgBT/)

Comment: I think it does. In the example code above the "don't do anything" block was just for illustrative purposes. If it's removed then the desired function runs **only** when the 'outer' div is clicked. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htnEQ/)

Comment: Yes, it does work after removing that if-statement. I updated my demos though to include one more complication: I put a nested div inside the outer div. Even with the if-statement removed, this does not handle that case. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z338u/1/) Of course, you may not have that situation.